# Postman eval() - how to evaluate a property part of Json

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a json response object like this:

```
"results": [
    {
        "seq": "882818::048313",
        "id": "user1"
    }
]
```

}

I have the entire json payload and id field name stored in 2 separate variables:

```
var jsonObj = pm.response.json();
var myfield = "id";
```

What I would like to do is below:

```
console.log("Value of id is: " + eval(jsonObj) + eval(".") +      eval(myField));
```

I tried this way and getting error: Unexpected identifier.

I don't want to hardcode the name of the property but instead make it dynamic.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your response body looks like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "seq": "882818::048313",
            "id": "user1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below statement will work (no need to use eval)

```
console.log("Value of id is: " +  jsonObj.results[0][myField]);
```